# autocomplete ._renderItem and adding a Class to wrapper

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Going off the example here http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data
I'm wondering how to add a style to the `ul` wrapper when using `_renderItem()`:

```
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here would be one simple way to do it, tapping into the `open` event:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: /* ... */,
    open: function () {
        $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.element.addClass("my_class");
    }
});
```

### jQueryUI >= 1.9

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: /* ... */,
    open: function () {
        $(this).data("uiAutocomplete").menu.element.addClass("my_class");
    }
});
```

`menu` is an internal widget that autocomplete uses.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/bx8Ye/

Comment: Just use `$(this).data('uiAutocomplete')` instead of 'autocomplete' for these versions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a style to the ul wrapper then you need to overload _renderMenu() and not _renderItem().

Here is an example that sets the width of the UL and adds a footer as the last li in the ul

```
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderMenu = function( ul, data ) {

    var self = this;
    $(ul).css('width', settings.dropDownWidth);

    $.each( data, function( index, item ) {
        self._renderItem( ul, item );
    });

    $(ul).append("<div class='myFooter'>some footer text</div>");
};
```

Comment: ERROR: `self._renderItem( ul, item );` is not a function

Comment: ERROR: `self = this.css("width", "900px");` `this.css` is not a function

Comment: Sorry about that, it was meant as an example not something you can cut and paste and just use.

Comment: here is a link to someone who answered the question better than I did... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435964/jqueryui-how-can-i-custom-format-the-autocomplete-plug-in-results

Comment: edited the answer to correct the bugs you pointed out. Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: @sngregory `ul` is already a jQuery object, no need to `$(ul)`

Answer (score 1):

When using jQuery UI 1.10, I used Andrew Whitaker's answer, but I had to change

```
$(this).data("autocomplete").menu.element.addClass("my_class");
```

to

```
$(this).data("uiAutocomplete").menu.element.addClass("my_class");
```