# Autocomplete set suggestion area width

Tags: jquery-ui

I use jquery combobox autocomplete like in the demo below.

[jquery combobox autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)

After i add [jQuery UI Autocomplete Select First Extension](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.selectFirst.js), i have problem with the width of suggestion area.

In some case, the width of suggestion area bigger than usual.
How to fix this problem?

I know i can put in this code :

*$(this).autocomplete("widget").css({"width": 250});*

but, it will change all of my combo style. So could i put in this code on every combobox i made?how can i do that?

thx.

Comment: could you add some of your code/css so we know what you are doing?

Comment: sure..its just like the demo above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just change the `css` for the `ul.ui-autocomplete` list. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/Q55Gj/2/)

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    width: 300px;
    background-color:red;
}    

.ui-autocomplete li {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

If you need to change the class for the results `ul`, then I would follow this link here to a solution. [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337796/autocomplete-renderitem-and-adding-a-class-to-wrapper)